AWS EKS : Creating a statefulset. Each replica with it's own persistent storage on EFS
I'm trying to deploy a statefulset with 3 replicas on AWS EKS, with each replica having it's own persistent storage(on efs) dynamically created.
The efs server address is stored in aws secrets manager.
But it's not working.
I'm getting the following error:
Warning FailedScheduling 4m58s default-scheduler 0/1 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
Any help is appreciated.
secrets-provider-class.yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: aws-secrets-provider
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects:  |
      - objectName: "efs-server-address"
        objectType: secretsmanager
        objectVersion: ""

efs-storageclass.yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: efs-storageclass
provisioner: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
parameters:
  secretProviderClass: "aws-secrets-provider"

eks-secrets-manager-efs-sa.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: eks-secrets-manager-efs-sa
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:policy/eks-secrets-manager-efs-policy

efs-pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-storageclass
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        fileSystemId: fs-0f012ab34567ab89c

statefulset-01.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: statefulset-01
  labels:
    app: app-sample-01
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-sample-01
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-sample-01
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: eks-secrets-manager-efs-sa
      containers:
        - name: container-sample-01
          image: '123456789000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sample-repo:latest'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: efs-volume
              mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: efs-volume
        spec:
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteMany
          storageClassName: efs-storageclass
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi

